# Laravel 8: How to send email notification to all admin users

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, one-to-many, laravel-8

I have a **One To Many** relationship between *User* Model & *Order* Model:

`User.php`:

```
public function order()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }
```

`Order.php`:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Now I need to access user instance from order:

```
$order = Order::where('id', $id)->update(['status' => 'verified', 'price' => $data['price']]);
$user = $order->user;
dd($user);
```

But in this way, I get this error:

`Trying to get property 'user' of non-object`

So how to solve this issue and access user instance properly?

Here is the Migration of `orders` table:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('material');
            $table->string('color');
            $table->string('dimensions');
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->tinyInteger('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: id field in the user table and user_id field in the order table must have same datatype, if you have used $table->id() in your user table then use $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable() in order table migration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update method wont return order detail's because update return `true` or `false`. So change it to

```
$order = Order::find($id);
$order->status='verified';
$order->price=$data['price'];
$order->save();
$user = $order->user;
```

**update** method takes array  as argument `update(array $values)` and return int

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you add in the migration the relation as a foreignID?

```
 $table->foreignID('user_id')->constrained();
```